# Posting images which are created by php

Tags: php, twitter, gd

I want to post created image to Twitter by Twitter api. 
I can post jpg, png or gif files to Twitter by code just below.

```
$params = array(
    'status' => 'This is my text',
    'media[]' => '/images/image.png'
);
$reply = $cb->statuses_updateWithMedia($params);
```

---

I have created a png image by this code:

```
header("Content-Type: image/png");
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im);
```

How can i post this image`($im)` to Twitter?

Comment: how about creating a temp image, posting it and then removing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need set header to save your image on disk. You just need to add second argument (filename) to `imagepng`:

```
$im = @imagecreate(110, 20)
    or die("Cannot Initialize new GD image stream");
$background_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  "A Simple Text String", $text_color);
imagepng($im, 'images/image.png');
```

After that you can use this image as you like.